# Restoring state in Android when using the 'up' button

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I am using `onSaveInstanceState()` to store an `ArrayList` member variable and restore it in the `onCreate()` method of the main activity.  This works in most circumstances such as rotating the screen etc. but if I open a new activity and use the 'up' button (not the back button) to navigate back to the main screen it seems to create a new main activity without passing the state bundle in `onCreate()`.

I have confirmed that when the up button is pressed the `onDestroy()` method is called for the original instance of the main activity which makes no sense to me because I want it to resume the existing activity as if I had pressed the back button rather than create a new one.

Is there a way I can force the new activity to restore the old one or just resume the existing activity?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, I had a basketball accident immediately after this post and then forgot about it until I started back on the project today! :S

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try setting the main activity's launch mode to singleTop, in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name="activityName" android:launchMode="singleTop" ... />
```

Comment: That should mean the activity doesn't get destroyed when you press the up button, so (in this case) you don't need the savedInstanceState - when the system destroys your activity to regain some resources (after you've navigated away from it), it will use the sIS bundle. Turn on 'dont keep activities' in ICS+ debug settings to mimic that

Comment: I would love an explanation of what "singleTop" does.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, MainScreenActivity.class);
  i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(i);
  finish();
```

This code should called on pressing up button.

Comment: I tried this method and it didn't work although I agree it should have from the description of FLAG_CLEAR_TOP